# How to check all column of a table in a database to same table exist in other databases in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a database and I have same table to other databases.I add some columns of the table of first database.Now I want to check that all off database's table are same or not.If its not then add those columns on those tables.Please give any kind of writing sp or another idea to do that

Comment: Use the schema compare in SQL Server Data Tools to build a migration script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to Check all the column names of  all tables present in a database.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Of course this may not be a complete answer for your question but thought this will help you in some way.

Comment: It will be more helpful if I can get any kind of procedure by executing which the task will more easy